# Checkbox-inline using Bootstrap, XML and XSL

Tags: xml, twitter-bootstrap, xslt

Hi I am trying to display inline check-boxes using Bootstrap.
I am using XML and XSL to render the html.  I am using class">col-sm-6 in my XSL and I am only able to display one check box in each column but would like to display at least 4 in each.

Do anyone have some solution for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"       version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="Application">
 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/applicationnew.css"></link>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="applications/scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="applications/scripts/common.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="applications/scripts/*id*.js"></script>   
</head>

<form  method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="saveApplication.aspx">
<div class="container">

<xsl:for-each select="Chapter">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body">

            <xsl:for-each select="Line">
            <div class="form-group">
            <xsl:variable name="propertycount" select="count(Property)" />
              <xsl:for-each select="Property">
              <div>
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$propertycount=1"><xsl:attribute name="class">col-sm-12</xsl:attribute></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:attribute name="class">col-sm-6       </xsl:attribute></xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:choose>
                   <xsl:when test="Type='CheckInLine'"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline">&#160;
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="../../Name" />
                          </xsl:attribute>
                          <xsl:attribute name="heiti">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Label" />
                          </xsl:attribute>

                          <xsl:attribute name="value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
                          </xsl:attribute>
                          &#160;<xsl:value-of select="Value" />
                        </input>
                  </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                    The type is wrong <xsl:value-of select="Type" />
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </div>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </div>                
          </xsl:for-each>
          </div>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>

 </div>
 </form>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<Application>
 <Id>0900</Id>
 <Title>Application</Title>

  <Chapter>
<Name>Reason</Name>
<Description></Description>
<Line>
  <Property>
    <Name>UnEmployee</Name>
    <Label></Label>
    <Required></Required>
    <Type>Check</Type>
    <Value>Box1</Value>
    <Class></Class>
    <Placeholder></Placeholder>
  </Property>
  <Property>
    <Name></Name>
    <Label></Label>
    <Required></Required>
    <Type>CheckInLine</Type>
    <Value>Box2</Value>
    <Class></Class>
    <Placeholder></Placeholder>
  </Property>
  <Property>
    <Name></Name>
    <Label></Label>
    <Required></Required>
    <Type>CheckInLine</Type>
    <Value>Box3</Value>
    <Class></Class>
    <Placeholder></Placeholder>
  </Property>
  </Line>
<Line>
  <Property>
    <Name>CantWork</Name>
    <Label></Label>
    <Required></Required>
    <Type>Check</Type>
    <Value>Box4:</Value>
    <Class></Class>
    <Placeholder></Placeholder>
  </Property>
  <Property>
    <Name></Name>
    <Label></Label>
    <Required></Required>
    <Type>Label</Type>
    <Value></Value>
    <Class></Class>
    <Placeholder></Placeholder>
  </Property>
</Line>

 </Chapter>

</Application>
```

Comment: Is this a html/css question, and you want to know what output will achieve the visual effect that you describe? Or is this an xslt question, where you know the desired html/css output and you need a stylesheet to do it? If the former, please re-tag. If the latter, please supply your expected output html/css.

Comment: Or maybe it is a bootstrap question? Do you need to know how to display 4 checkboxes per column, in general? or with bootstrap css?

Comment: This is an xslt question and I need a stylesheet to do it.

Comment: Please show your expected output html.

Comment: A picture is useless. Please post your expected output html as code, not at a picture.

Comment: Sorry Sean.  Expected html outpu is in now.

Comment: Your expected result is not connected to your XSLT and the original ask. Where is col-sm-6 class in the sample? Can you produce the actual output and modify it manually so that it looks how you need it, and post it here? (And separate it from XML, please)

Answer (score 0):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0" >
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />    

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" />
      <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
      <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="application.js" />
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
       <div class="col-sm-6">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Application/Chapter" />
       </div>
     </div> 
   </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Chapter">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Boxes:</h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-inline">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Line/Property" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Property" />

<xsl:template match="Property[Type='CheckInLine']">
  <div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label><xsl:value-of select="Value" /></label>
   </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will transform this input document ...

```
<Application>
 <Id>0900</Id>
 <Title>Application</Title>

  <Chapter>
<Name>Reason</Name>
<Description></Description>
<Line>
  <Property>
    <Name>UnEmployee</Name>
    <Label></Label>
    <Required></Required>
    <Type>Check</Type>
    <Value>Box1</Value>
    <Class></Class>
    <Placeholder></Placeholder>
  </Property>
  <Property>
    <Name></Name>
    <Label></Label>
    <Required></Required>
    <Type>CheckInLine</Type>
    <Value>Box2</Value>
    <Class></Class>
    <Placeholder></Placeholder>
  </Property>
  <Property>
    <Name></Name>
    <Label></Label>
    <Required></Required>
    <Type>CheckInLine</Type>
    <Value>Box3</Value>
    <Class></Class>
    <Placeholder></Placeholder>
  </Property>
  </Line>
<Line>
  <Property>
    <Name>CantWork</Name>
    <Label></Label>
    <Required></Required>
    <Type>Check</Type>
    <Value>Box4:</Value>
    <Class></Class>
    <Placeholder></Placeholder>
  </Property>
  <Property>
    <Name></Name>
    <Label></Label>
    <Required></Required>
    <Type>Label</Type>
    <Value></Value>
    <Class></Class>
    <Placeholder></Placeholder>
  </Property>
</Line>

 </Chapter>

</Application>
```

... into this output html document ...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="application.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Boxes:</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-inline">
              <div class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox"><label>Box2</label></div>
              <div class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox"><label>Box3</label></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```